# how to protect our app by using obfuscation[proguard] in android studio

Tags: android, security, android-proguard

I am searching for protecting my app by using proguard but I didnt find proper answer how to protect my app.
   If any body know how to protect our app using obfuscation in proguard help me.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android Studio

1. Go to build.gradle file of your app
2. Check for below snippet in the file

> Put minifyEnabled as 'true';

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                                                 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
}
```

3. In proguard-rules.pro add excpetions and rules matching your app.

E.g.

```
-keep public class * extends android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity
-keep public class * extends your.package.name.SomeClass
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

Comment: Hi balu Give me any sample examples using proguard or post any websites

Comment: That is what i have done here. I have posted a sample with steps.

Comment: Thanks balu but actually I have done like this only but I didnt got.Share how to write proguard rules stepystep

Comment: Actually I am new to proguard so this is first time I am working on proguard,so I am facing little bit difficult

Comment: Post your proguard file

Comment: I am following procedure but at one point I am doing small mistake